# BufferedReader, can't read BMP. TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program should read information about the bitmap from the buffer. It's written in Python 3.8.

The problem is with this line of code.

```
image_w, image_h, image_bpp, image_data = MyLoadBMP("test.bmp")
```

The compiler spits the error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object
```

I suppose the error might be in how the variable is defined, but I have no idea how to change that. Variables are defined this way.

**It's hint, and it isn't changing the code.**

`image_w: Union[None, Unknown] image_h: Union[None, Unknown] image_bpp: Union[None, Unknown] image_data: Union[None, Unknown]`

Below, I am attaching the defined functions related to the bug.

```
def MyLoadBMP(filename):
    # Read the entire file into the buffer.
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        data = f.read()

    if data[:2] != 'BM':
        # Invalid BMP file.
        return None

    # Will extract BITMAPFILEHEADER
    bfType, bfSize, bfRes1, bfRes2, bfOffBits = struct.unpack("<HIHHI", data[:14])

    # Will extract BITMAPINFOHEADER.
    (biSize, biWidth, biHeight, biPlanes, biBitCount, biCompression, biSizeImage, biXPelsPerMeter, biYPelsPerMeter, biClrUser, biClrImportant) = struct.unpack("<IIIHHIIIIII", data[14:14 + 40])

    if biSize != 40:
        # Unsupported BMP variant.
        return None
    
    if biBitCount == 24 and biCompression == 0: #BI_RGB
        return MyLoadBMP_RGB24(data, bfOffBits, biWidth, biHeight)

    # Encoding not supported.
    return None

def MyLoadBMP_RGB24(data, pixel_offset, w, h):
    # Are the poems written from bottom to top?
    bottom_up = True
    if h < 0:
        bottom_up = False
        h = - h
    
    # Calculate the pitch.
    pitch = (w * 3 + 3) & ~3

    # Create a new buffer for the read bitmap (24BPP, color order: BGR).

    bitmap = array.array('B', [0]) * w * h * 3

    # Load lines.
    if bottom_up:
        r = range(h - 1, -1, -1)
    else:
        r = range(0, h)

    for y in r:
        for x in range(0, w):
            bitmap[(x + y * w * 3 + 0)] = ord(data[pixel_offset + x * 3 + 0])
            bitmap[(x + y * w * 3 + 1)] = ord(data[pixel_offset + x * 3 + 1])
            bitmap[(x + y * w * 3 + 2)] = ord(data[pixel_offset + x * 3 + 2])
        pixel_offset += pitch

    return (w, h, 24, bitmap)
```

Comment: Type hints like `image_w: Union[None, Unknown]` are hints only, they don't change the code.

Comment: If your function encounters a file it can't handle, you should do something like `raise ValueError("Invalid BMP file")`, so that you can tell what went wrong, rather than returning a `None` that the caller is going to choke on.

Comment: `if data[:2] != 'BM':` was problematic, it has to be `if data[:2] != b'BM':` to read bytes instead of strings :)
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your function returned `None`, presumably because you hit one of these 3 cases in your code:

```
if data[:2] != 'BM':
    # Invalid BMP file.
    return None

# ...

if biSize != 40:
    # Unsupported BMP variant.
    return None

if biBitCount == 24 and biCompression == 0: #BI_RGB
    # ...

# Encoding not supported.
return None
```

You can't unpack `None`:

```
>>> image_w, image_h, image_bpp, image_data = None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Test for the result *first*, then unpack:

```
result = MyLoadBMP("test.bmp")
if result is None:
    # handle separately
else:
    image_w, image_h, image_bpp, image_data = result
```